# How to parse a html table data through table id using JSoup in java

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup, html-parser

I need to store my client's table data into database.

There are n number of tables for which they have not provided any table class (directly using just Table_id in web page).

Example:

```
[table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  id="AutoNumber5" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111"]<br/>
[table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  id="AutoNumber4" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" ]
```

If there is a Table Class, obviously i can parse it easily, but there is no class just id is given in table.

I know there would be only one word syntax, except

```
for (Element table : doc.select("table")
```

Maybe I could not find it. How to find it ?
I have tried

`for (Element table : doc.select("table.AutoNumber5")`

But it's not working for me.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
doc.select("table#AutoNumber5");
```

It worked for me.

**Reference :**
 http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html

Answer (score 3):

jsoup support css selectors and if you know the css it is easy to use like this:

> Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://xxxxxxxx.com/").get();
>
> Elements el = doc.select("#targeted-elemnet-id");

you only need to replace your element id after # sign without space.